# How to Sort the TreeMap based on keys and get the First entry

Tags: java

I have a TreeMap , i want to sort the TreeMap based on keys and get the first entry

This is what i tried , but i am getting output as 1233 
As number 12 (key)is bigger , i am expecting output to be 444

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeMap;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
          TreeMap<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(new MyComp());
         treeMap.put("9", "1233");
         treeMap.put("l2", "444");
         treeMap.comparator();
         String first = ((TreeMap<String, String>) treeMap).firstEntry().getValue();
         System.out.println(first);
    }
}

class MyComp implements Comparator<String>{
    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        return str1.compareTo(str2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are **not** putting "12" (twelve) in the map, you are putting "l2" (lowercase letter L, followed by 2) in the map. Fix that and you get "444" as the result.

Comment: The `TreeMap` is *already* sorted on the keys. That's what it's *for.*

Comment: Secondly, you will be getting the *smallest* entry from the map. The **string** "12" (the string) is **smaller** than "9" (not bigger, as you say) because you chose to put *strings* in the map, not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `TreeMap` to be sorted according to the numeric value of the string keys, you'll need a `Comparator` that parses those strings. With JDK 8, it's an elegant one liner:

```
TreeMap<String, String> treeMap = 
    new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt));
```